# Copy files and folder to WEB-INF using Ant

Tags: ant, copy, war

I want to copy a .properties file from a certain location to my *WEB-INF/classes/com/infiniti* folder(in a WAR file).

I have gone through this link [How to get Ant to copy properties file to classes directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731085/how-to-get-ant-to-copy-properties-file-to-classes-directory)
using which I can copy the .properties file to *WEB-INF/classes/* but not to *WEB-INF/classes/com/infiniti*

Code I am using is:

```
<war destfile="${deploy}/acc.war" webxml="${warSrc}/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <lib dir="${lib}">
.......
.......
.......
            <classes dir="${configHome}/config/com/infiniti">
                <include name="accredit.properties" />
            </classes>

...
....
.......
</war>
```

Also I need to copy *${configHome}/resources/com/infiniti/errorcode* folder to 
*WEB-INF/classes/com/infiniti*.

Is this possible using Ant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes, you can use for instance [ZipFileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) like this

```
<war destfile="${deploy}/acc.war" webxml="${warSrc}/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
...
    <zipfileset dir="${configHome}/config/com/infiniti" includes="**/*.properties" prefix="WEB-INF/classes/com/infiniti"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michele...you just saved me 2 hours of task everyday :)...Its working smooth...also for the second part of my question (to copy folder)...I have used this <zipfileset dir="${configHome}/resources/com/infiniti/errorcode" prefix="WEB-INF/classes/com/infiniti/errorcode"/>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using ant. Just use the copy or sync commands to move your file:

```
<copy todir="${distribution}/location" file="${local.path}/data/file.txt">
</copy>
```

You can also copy with rules:

```
<copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${combined.bin}">
  <fileset dir="${buildbin}"/>
  <fileset dir="${output2buildbin}"/>
  <fileset dir="${output3buildbin}"/>
</copy>
```

Using sync:

```
<sync includeemptydirs="false" todir="${distres}">
  <fileset dir="${buildres}">
    <include name="logging/**" />
  </fileset>
</sync>
```

Tasks are described on their doc site:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

The same 'fileset' declarative applies to the war task:

```
Examples

Assume the following structure in the project's base directory:

thirdparty/libs/jdbc1.jar
thirdparty/libs/jdbc2.jar
build/main/com/myco/myapp/Servlet.class
src/metadata/myapp.xml
src/html/myapp/index.html
src/jsp/myapp/front.jsp
src/graphics/images/gifs/small/logo.gif
src/graphics/images/gifs/large/logo.gif

then the war file myapp.war created with

<war destfile="myapp.war" webxml="src/metadata/myapp.xml">
  <fileset dir="src/html/myapp"/>
  <fileset dir="src/jsp/myapp"/>
  <lib dir="thirdparty/libs">
    <exclude name="jdbc1.jar"/>
  </lib>
  <classes dir="build/main"/>
  <zipfileset dir="src/graphics/images/gifs"
              prefix="images"/>
</war>

will consist of

WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/lib/jdbc2.jar
WEB-INF/classes/com/myco/myapp/Servlet.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
index.html
front.jsp
images/small/logo.gif
images/large/logo.gif
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html

Comment: I tried copy but seems like copy is not supported under war tag....gave me this error while using <copy> 'war doesn't support the nested "copy" element"

Comment: it should support filesets. Look at the examples from the doc.